# Really throw an error inside a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, try-catch

Let's say I have a function which takes some input and does some operation on the input inside a promise. Rather than just returning a promise in a rejected state, if the input is "invalid" I'd like my function to throw an error. The problem is that right now the promise catches the error and moves to a rejected state. Is this possible?

Example:

```
function myFunc(input) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (input) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      throw 'invalid input!'; // ideally this should really throw, rather than just reject
    }
  });
}
```

I've been playing around with this and am beginning to think this isn't possible, but I figured I'd ask here to see if anyone has an idea for how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the general case, if you don't want to use async/await, this isn't possible as the error may happen long after the function myFunc returns.

Comment: Why not just throw the error inside of your reject callback?

Comment: Promises must resolve or reject. The throw must reject the promise or the promise is left pending and no way to complete the promise. You can not call resolve/reject after you throw as throw terminates execution hence any thrown errors call reject.

Comment: @mhodges as Blindman67 points out doing that won't actually throw an error, just reject the promise.

Comment: @winhowes Right.. so why can't you `reject("Invalid Input")` and in your `myFunc().then(function resolveCallback () {...}, function rejectCallback(reason) { throw reason; });` ? In other words, send your error message to your reject callback, and then let your callback throw the actual error.

Comment: @mhodges That won't throw an error. It will just make the promise returned from rejectCallback be in the rejected state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the input before you build the return Promise and throw there. That is throwing in myFunc.

```
function myFunc(input) {
  if (!input)
      throw "invalid input!"
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       // do stuff
       resolve(result);
       //if doesn't work
       reject(reason);

  });
}
```

It will not give you the promise object and throws a error if the input is empty which is what you want I assume.

```
try{
    myFunc();
}
catch(e)
{
    console.log("It does throw and doesn't give you the promise", e)
}
```

If you want the code in the promise to say, there is an error, what you really need to do is rejecting ... which is what reject is for. Basically if you want to throw in the promise you return, you should reject.

Reject and catch the error when using the promise.

```
p1.then((result) => {
        // deal with result
    })
    .catch((reason)=>{
        // you get the error you rejected in the promise
    });
```

Comment: Right, yeah unfortunately the input in my specific case can only be checked inside of a promise, but yes this is conclusion I've come to :/ Just making sure there's not some obscure way to avoid the calling function having to catch the reject

Comment: Just like if you have a function A returning a function B, and in the function B you return if you throw, the function A will not throw when executed. It will only throw when function B is executed. In this case function A is not returning a function B but a promise.